# Why is the property of JSON object not accessible?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm not able to access `progress` property of `data` object. I used `debugger` to stop the application and check if `data` object is defined. Here's the screenshot of the console and it completely makes no sense.

[image: Console Screenshot]

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Comment: Can you share your code and how your JSON object is defined ? and where you are calling it ?

Comment: You don't need the code, there is sufficient information in the screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data` is an `Array`. You want `data[0].progress`.

Comment: *Bashes his head against the wall and gets back* Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Data is an array, as evidenced by the fact that in the console it has brackets.

In order to access the object inside it, you need to use array index notation, like so:

```
data[0].progress  //0
```